# Issue with Prompts when SSH from Tmux to Remote Host

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, tmux

I have a Tmux session running locally, in one of the panes I ssh to another host, however once the remote machine is logged in, the cursor is overwriting the command prompt. I think this is happening because the prompt is different widths on the local and remote machine, e.g:

Local:

```
 foo>
```

Remote:

```
[foo@dev-host-app00 ~]$
```

So in the above example the cursor is flashing over the @ sign and overwriting past it as I type. It seems to think that the prompt with on the remote machine is same width as on the local machie. Can someone please point me at what I might need to do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer thanks to a colleague. Posting here in case it helps someone else:

On the remote side, TERM was being set to 'TERM=screen-xterm256' which was not recognised on the remote side since this setting is specific to tmux.

Launching the pane as follows solved the issue:

```
TERM=xterm ssh user@remote
```

Comment: Please mark this as accepted so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions :-)